# Nodemon not working in some paths, works in others

Tags: node.js, windows, express, web-development-server, nodemon

To start out I realize people on here hate when a question is asked but its been asked on here before, the other questions answers have not solved my problems. I'm starting a project and when I gave the command nodemon server to start and run the file the command prompt tells me. And it is also installed globaly.

```
'update' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Nodemon works in other folders where I need it to but not in my current folder. I did just have to update my windows computer and I realize this probably is what started the problem but I am completely lost and need help.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I feel goofy for this but in the path leading to that folder one of the names of the folder had & in it. Make sure yall dont do this if you run into this problem.

Comment: Better add an example